# Meta title tag encoding special characters that are already encoded

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The title is coming from the database. It displays properly in the page but not in the title tag. I have tried many helper functions in ruby to try to fix it, but nothing seems to work. It seems to be encoding it when it is already encoded it.

In view page.html.erb

```
<% content_for :title, "#{@adventure.title} |" %>
```

Title in window: **AVENTURE D'UN JOUR**

In page source:

```
<title>AVENTURE D&amp;#39;UN JOUR</title>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the code look like in the page view/partial ?

Comment: @ReggieB updated my question by adding the code in view.

Comment: And what does the code where the content is used/rendered look like? I expect that's in the layout file as you are using `content_for`, and is something like `yield :title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that erb code should be:

```
<% content_for :title, @adventure.title %>
```

Then if the title is being defined in your layout file header as:

```
<title><%= yield :title %></title>
```

Then you will need to unencode it there:

```
<title><%= CGI.unescapeHTML(yield :title) %></title>
```

Comment: This actually helped me find the correct solution. I need the string interpolation in this case, but I was trying to fix the encoded html in the page view rather than the layout. The page view stayed the same and in the layout I added <title><%= CGI.unescapeHTML("#{yield(:title)} #{t('website_name')}") %></title>